# Console / Terminal becomes useless after an Error occurs in multithreaded code

Tags: python

I've noticed this lately: If i run a multithreaded Python script from windows cmd prompt, or a terminal on Linux, and an Error is raised somewhere in the multithreaded code, the execution stops with the appropriate messages, but then I can't do anything to break out of this and return to prompt. The only option is to close the cmd or Terminal and reopen it, which is kind of time consuming and annoying. How can i avoid this?

Comment: I'd be concerned that your code raises exceptions often enough that this is a problem.  In any case, are you using multithread or multiprocess?

Comment: Use Ctrl+Z instead of Ctrl+C

Comment: Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z don't work. @sr2222 its just some script im running, not polished yet

Comment: PS: im using Queue and Thread classes

Comment: Someone tell me if I'm talking nonsense, please. In a multithreaded environment, wouldn't it be appropriate for the threads to catch the exception and do something with it? Logging it somewhere is a must, of course, but I imagine that the thread should also either `exit(1)` (or whatever non-zero exit code you want) to cleanly kill the program or, if it is truly non-fatal, swallow the exception so that other threads can continue.

Comment: In a production environment i totally agree. But im only doing some smple testing, and everytime an uncatched error is thrown in single threaded part, the program exists back to prompt, while in the multithreaded part it doesnt, despite the fact that all threads fail. I think the reason might be because the queue object isnt empty yet. But its still wird why ctrl-c or z don't work in this case